# hibernate validiate list of integer

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have a list of integer like this:

```
private List<Integer> indexes;
```

Is there a way to valid individual member to be in a range of 0-9? I see @Range and @Valid but can't find a way to make it work with List.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: It doesn't work with @Range. The error is: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>

Answer (score 1):

Only @Size and @Valid can be used on Collections, however you can use some wrapper object instead of "Integer" to validate your ints, e.g.:

```
public class Index {
  @Range( min = 0, max = 9 )
  private Integer value;
}

public class Container {
  @Valid
  private List<Index> indexes;
}
```

This should do the trick